# Find $\lim_{x\to0}(1+x^{2})^{\cot^2{x}}$ without lhopital

Tags: limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital

I need to find $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x^{2})^{\cot^2{x}}$.

I started like this:

$\lim_{x\to0}(1+x^{2})^{\cot^2{x}} = \lim_{x\to0}e^{\ln(1+x^{2})^{\cot^2{x}}} = \lim_{x\to0}e^{\cot^2{x} \cdot \ln(1+x^{2})} = \lim_{x\to0}e^{\frac{\cos^2{x}}{\sin^2{x}} \cdot \ln(1+x^{2})}$

Now I'm not sure about this one but can I say:

$\lim_{x\to0}e^{\frac{\cos^2{x}}{\sin^2{x}} \cdot \ln(1+x^{2})} = \lim_{x\to0}e^{\frac{x^2}{\sin^2{x}} \cdot \ln(1+x^{2})}$?

if so than

$ \lim_{x\to0}e^{\frac{x^2}{\sin^2{x}} \cdot \ln(1+x^{2})} = \lim_{x\to0}e^{1 \cdot \ln(1)} = e^0 = 1$

Is this valid? Is there a better way

Comment: How did you replace $\cos^2 x$ with $x^2$?

Comment: The answer is $e$. See my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take the log we get 
$$\cot^2 x \ln(1+x^2)=\cos^2 x \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{\sin^2 x}$$
write as

$$\cos^2 x \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^2}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}\to 1$$
by standard limits. Easy peasy.

Comment: How can you tell that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^2}=1$? Is it:
$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\ln((1+x^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2}} )=  \lim_{t\to 0}\ln((1+t)^{\frac{1}{t}}) = \ln(e) = 1$?

Comment: @juniven This is just $\frac{ln(1+x)}{x}\to 1$. When you talk about showing this, you must remember that it is one of the basic limits of the theory and depends on the properties unique to $e$. Also when we say $d(\ln x)=\frac{1}{x}$ this is just a restatement of the above limit. So it is really a question of how far back in the limit theory one wants to go. For myself I take it as a basis for all further limit calculations. Its a restatement of $\frac{e^x -1}{x}\to 1$.

Comment: @Rene Schipperus Okay, got the point.

Comment: @juniven Ok, but the comment of S.Peter above is a nice proof.

Comment: @Rene Schipperus Yeah, its nicely done

Comment: The answer is $e$.

Comment: @Gyanshu Yeah but I took the log....so I get one.

Comment: At the end you get $log_e(answer) = 1$. $\therefore$ answer $= e^1$. Remember you took log both sides at the starting of the problem?

Comment: @Gyanshu Oh dear prof, am I going to lose marks ?

Comment: sure if you do that in an exam ;P

Comment: @Gyanshu The fact of the matter is that I shall never take another exam in this life.

Comment: Then you won't loose any marks.Fine? :P

Comment: @Gyanshu Anyway I never cared about marks only my own knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x^2)^{\cot^2x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x^2)^{\frac {1}{x^2}x^2\cot^2x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x^2)^{\frac {1}{x^2}{(\frac{x}{\sin x})}^2\cos^2x}$$
We know
$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin x} = 1$
So
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x^2)^{\frac {1}{x^2}\cos^2x}$$
and $\cos0= 1$.
Also $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^\frac{1}{x} = e$.

Thus,
$$\implies \lim_{x\to 0}(1+x^2)^{\frac {1}{x^2}}=e$$

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't say that.  $\cos^2 x$ and $x^2$ are not very much alike close to $0$.  The limit is actually $e$.  But your tag says "limits without L'hospital", and I don't see a way to get $e$ without it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x^{2})^{\cot^2{x}}$$

- If you know that $\frac{\sin x}{x}\to1$ as $x\to0$ (or, equivalently, that $\frac{\tan x}{x}\to1$ as $x\to0$), then you can deduce that $x^2\cot^2x\to1$ as $x\to0$.

  - This first limit can be proved by geometric methods, and is fairly standard.
- If you know that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\to e$ as $n\to\infty$, substituting $n=x^{-2}$ allows you to infer that $(1+x^2)^{1/x^2}\to e$ as $x\to0$.

Thus:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x^{2})^{\cot^2{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left[(1+x^{2})^{1/x^2}\right]^{x^2\cot^2 x}=e^1=e$$